# How can you conditionally set services in the docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cakebuild

I'm new to using Docker and Cake. At the moment we have a simple Cake task that runs the DockerComposeUp() method that takes a DockerComposeUpSettings object. The docker-compose.yaml file holds some info on a service that I want to conditionally run (serviceA):

```
version: "1.0"  
services:  
    serviceA:  
        image: someImage  
        ports:
          -"000000"
          -"000001"
    serviceB:
        image: someOtherImage
        anotherProperty: somethingElse
        ports:
          -"111111"
```

I've tried splitting out serviceA into a separate docker-compose file called 'docker-compose.serviceA.yaml' and calling it by adding to the DockerComposeUpSettings.ArgumentCustomization the following:

```
if(some setting)
{
    dockerComposeUpSettings.ArgumentCustomization = builder => builder.Append("-f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose.serviceA.yaml");
}
```

However, Cake throws the following error:

> "unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f"

How can I merge to docker-compose files as part of the DockerComposeUp method using Cake?

***Update***

I've found there is a 'Files' property on the DockerComposeUpSettings object (inherited from DockerComposeSettings object), where you can declare the configuration files. So I've added:

```
if(some flag)
{
    dockerComposeSettings.Files = new[]{ "docker-compose.yaml", "docker-compose.serviceA.yaml" };
}
```

Comment: The idea of splitting the `yaml` file is a valid option. Exactly why it's not working for you is not related to docker or docker-compose, but whatever tool you are using to run it (Cake?). You should clarify your question if that's the case.

Comment: @super - yes, it's Cake, but there's not tag on SO for it (just CakePHP). I'll update with a link to the docs

Comment: Updated with correct tag 'CakeBuild'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about docker, but looking at the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) it seems it would be important to have the `-f` option set before the command specified on the commandline. Your customization (`builder.Append()`) puts them at the end of the commandline.

Have you tried setting the `Files` property of the [DockerComposeUpSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerComposeSettings/)? That looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I found the 'Files' property shortly after posting this. It seems to do what I want and I've got it working.